# problem with uploade image by Http in laravel liveware

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-livewire

i want to uplode image in livewire and send to https in api, i use this code

```
$response = Http::attach('photo', $this->photo, 'photo.jpg' ,['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'])
        ->post('http://localhost:8001/api/v1/client/profile/1', [
            '_method' => 'PUT',
        ]);
```

i handler request by this

```
$path = $request->file('photo')->store('photo', 'public');
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Your API handler executed successfully',
            'data' =>$path,
        ]);
```

my probleme image is storage in type file txt not jpg

```
array:2 [▼ // app\Livewire\Profile.php:70
  "message" => "Your API handler executed successfully"
  "data" => "photo/oZjgfEnq0BvvuHsAKRbpV4J21FP8YgbNSoPtinO3.txt"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same error in the past

and from my research i found that you can only upload files in `post` method

so try to change request method to `post`

Comment: Honestly, I tried several methods, but the same problem